# How to Search Specific Sentence in Text File

Tags: java, full-text-search, file-handling

i've a Text File in which Book are save.
i'me wanted to search Book like this.
BY BookTitle or Book Publisher
if user Select any of this opation it display Related Books.

BookID      Title       Publisher

305     HTML5       Press
100     Java        BookShop
200     Games       ApPress

300     Computer    PCWorld

i try with Tokenized but Separate break the sentence like this
305
HTML
Press

Comment: Could you paste the code you already tried and the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take 3 arrays or lists and store every column's values in one list or array. Fill your lists by reading line by line  of file and by splitting every line with space and insert every value in corresponding list or array.
you can search for specific value in list or array. on the same index in remaining lists you can find other info also.
hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can read the file or text into a string variable and then applies some Regular Expression to find some text pattern.

Comment: It, will be more easy if you can upload you code into gitHub